# How to create utility color classes in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to be able to create, what I think, is called a utility class for a particular set of colors in my color theme to help get rid of unnecessary code, and just be able to type the name -- ei - primary-green -- instead of the color code.

For example

```
.titleAbout {
color: primary-green;
}
```

I know I can do it with Sass and scss, but is there a way to keep it in my css file. I'm developing my own wordpress theme and it wants it to remain in a css.

For examples: in a Sass .scss it would look like this

```
// Delta Theme Colors 

$primary-green: #16571D;
$bg-green: #7fb985;
$title-Purple: #4E1282;
$primary-blue:#3051C7;
$primary-yellow: #F0AF13;
$primary-orange: #D66550;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth looking into CSS custom properties - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: Perfect! Thanks,  I was using the wrong name when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use CSS custom properties or so-called variables.

- To declare them use

```
:root {
  --primary-green: #16571d;
  --bg-green: #7fb985;
  --title-Purple: #4e1282;
  --primary-blue: #3051c7;
  --primary-yellow: #f0af13;
  --primary-orange: #d66550;
}
```

- To use them use `var(--property-name)`

```
background-color: var(--primary-orange);
```

---

**Check it in action below:**

```css
:root {
  --primary-blue: #3051c7;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--primary-blue);
}
```

---

> [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)